# Delete record in database with bindingnavigator

Tags: .net, bindingsource

Hi I navigate with a bindingnavigator threw a datagridview. this datagridview is connected with a database.
If I want to delete a row on the datagridview then it deletes it perfectly, But the row in the database stays.

```
    private void deletetoolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (MessageBox.Show("Delete record?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
       {
          //bindingSource1.RemoveCurrent();
          DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow);
       }
    }
```

How to fetch the record specific details for sending a parameter to the database and delete the record for real  with my next function ?

```
deleteRecordDataGridView(parameter);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind I solved it like this

```
          DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)bindingSource1.Current;
          string e1 = drv.Row[0].ToString();
```

Comment: How did that solve it? What does getting `e1` have to do with deleting the record?